# Linux terminal is not recognizing login information

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, login

I recently got a big problem with my Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya: after an `apt get update` and restart, the interface isn't able to properly open anymore. Everytime I enter in one of the accounts, the interface crashes with a message saying "Cinammon stopped working. You are executing it in recovery mode. Do you want to restart Cinnamon?" (personal translation from Portuguese) and it gives me two options, Yes or No. If I type "Yes", the same problem appears; if I type "No", the PC gets into a partially started state.

Searching about the problem on the web, I found some possible solutions that involve running Linux Terminal from `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and removing some recently installed updates. When I enter the terminal, it shows the message:

```
Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya daniel-EMB tty1:

daniel-EMB login:
```

There are three accounts on this machine: daniel, martin and admin. The last one I don't know the password, but everytime I type either the first or the second and with the correct passwords, Linux rejects my login info claiming `Login incorrect`. Because of this I'm being unable to work with the Terminal to solve the Cinnamon problem.

I tried to find some solution on the web without success. Other cases of login in Linux terminal not being accepted were in different circunstances and different messages were being given.

So why does the Linux terminal don't accept my correct login info? And how can I make it work? Is there a way I can use the Terminal without having to provide this login info? And is it possible to bypass the situation and solve the update problem with a different Linux run from a pendrive?

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to find a solution: the two passwords of both martin and daniel accounts required special characters and numbers and I was using the numeric keyboard to type both of them. I decided to give it a try and type it only with the main keyboard and my password was then recognized. For whatever reason typing passwords with the numeric keyboard in Linux Terminal isn't a viable move.

Comment: Try activating/deactivating `NumLock` on the keyboard.